# RSA проблема с расшифровкой

Tags: c#, rsa, decrypt

Работаю над алгоритмом RSA и в целом все получается, но есть проблема с расшифровкой. Для некоторых чисел, таких как 9, 10, 13 происходит неверная расшифровка сообщения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
private void button_GetKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = p * q; // Модуль, который используется в открытом ключе
        int f = (p - 1) * (q - 1);  // Функция Эйлера

        List<int> simpleNumbers = generateSimpleNumbers(f);
        int exp = getExponent(simpleNumbers, f);
        // На данном этапе у нас есть открытый ключ {exp, n}
        //Далее необхожимо сформировафть личный ключ 
        int d = generatePrivateKey(exp, f); // личный ключ {d, n}

        // Теперь можем приступать к кодированию
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //Получить случайное число
        double x = rnd.Next(1, n);
        textBox5.Text = x.ToString();
        x = Math.Pow(x, exp);
        x = x % n;
        textBox3.Text = x.ToString();

        // После приступаем к дешифровке
        double y = Math.Pow(x, d);
        y = y % n;
        textBox4.Text = y.ToString();
    }

    private bool isSimpleNumber(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0) count++;
        }

        if (count == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private List<int> generateSimpleNumbers(int n)
    {
        int count;
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0) count++;
            }

            if (count == 1)
                numbers.Add(i);
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    // Находим экспоненту
    private int getExponent(List<int> numbers, int fi)
    {
        foreach (int el in numbers)
        {
            if (fi % el != 0)
                return el;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Находим личный ключ
    private int generatePrivateKey(int e, int fi)
    {
        int d = e;
        int test = 0;
        do
        {
            d += 1;
            test = (d * e) % fi;

        } while (!isSimpleNumber(d) || test != 1);

        return d;
    }
```

Почему в некоторых моментах нарушается расшифровка ? Ведь условие (x < n) не нарушается. Отталкивался вот от этого [источника](http://www.michurin.net/computer-science/rsa.html)

Comment: всё в вашем коде не так да этак: методы нужно писать с большой буквы, даже приватные; `List<int>` -> `IEnumerable<int>` ([оператор yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)) + не нужно указывать количество элементов, т.к. это `IEnumerable` — мы извлекаем елемент по 1-му и останавливаемся, когда реализация `IEnumerable` захочет (спойлер: никогда, т.к. простых чисел бесконечно много); `if (count == 1) return true; else return false;` -> `return count == 1;`

Comment: также не оптимальная реализация у `IsSimpleNumber` — можно так `for (...) { if (n % i) count++; if (count > 1) return false; } return count == 1;`; тоже самое и в `GenerateNumbers` — `for (...) { for(...) { if (i % j == 0) count++; if (count > 1) break; } }`

Comment: [генератор простых чисел с `IEnumerable`1`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196592/prime-numbers-generator). кстати — простое число на англ. будет prime number.

Comment: вообще, если вы пишете под Visual Studio, то можете отладить ваш код и посмотреть, где ошибка. [документация по отладке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger). просто сейчас не понятно, где искать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильный алгоритм нахождения секретного ключа.

```cs
long ComputPrivateKey(long e, long phi)
{
    var d = 1;

    while ((d * e - 1) % phi != 0) d++;

    return d;
}
```

Мой вариант также не оптимальный, зато простой. За сложными вариантами вам [сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) — всю информацию об RSA я брал оттуда.

---

Вообще вам нужно по-хорошему использовать большие числа (по 1024 бит, например), иначе у вас может быть переполнение и все ваши данные полетят коту под хвост.